# Can't remove unconfirmed transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, armory

Armory 0.95.1
Bitcoin core 0.14.1

I am stuck with a payment that has the state "not in the blockchain yet".

I already updated armory and bitcoin core, tried to rebuild the database and did the "clear all unconfirmed" command.

I added a fee of 0.0001 Bitcons to it, never had issues with this. The transaction was initiated several hours ago, it still has 0 confirmations.

According to blockchain.info the current confirmation time shouldn't be longer than 100mins...

Comment: 0.0001 should be too little at current fee levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to select "remove all unconfirmed" and export the priv58 keys of your wallet.

The second step would be to import the priv58 keys into a working client, like bitcoin core.

The syntax is as follows:

```
importprivkey <key>
```

Answer (score 2):

Armory 0.95.1 is incompatible with Bitcoin Core 0.14.1. Use Bitcoin Core 0.13.2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

1) Clearing unconfirmed transactions is broken with 0.95.x

2) You can't RBF/CPFP with 0.95.x

3) 0.95 does not work with Core 0.14's refactored network layer

Your best path of action is to try out 0.96 and CPFP the unconfirmed transactions (using the Coin Control GUI in Expert mode):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1849994.0